# How to loop parse pattern from MySql table using python

Tags: python, mysql, regex, scrapy

I'm trying to parse scrapy result with regex, the thing is my regex patterns located in MySQL table.. i have trouble to loop the pattern in sequence in order to return clean content without any html tags..
simply say html result scrapy -> parse with pattern in row1 (ex: clean html above content), parse with pattern in row2 (clean html below content) , ..... -> clean

example

```
<body>
 <title>
 <some tags>
  <content>
 <footer tags>
 <another tags>
</body>
```

i'm trying to clean that html, with this table, field name (pattern , sequence, replacer), values:

```
row1    <body.*?some tags>  1  None
row2    <footer.*?/body>    2  None
row3    <br>                3  Enter
row4    #&quot              4  ""
```

so i have a clean content in return, i'm using regex replace pattern, not xpath match, because i'm expecting to scrap a lot of web with their own html tags variation

here's my code , it didn't raise an error but the result is repeated.. it supposed to be 1 clean result from 1 scrapy result. i think i did something wrong, but can't figure it out since i'm new in python and scrapy

```
   def parse(self, response):
    for mbuh in response.xpath('//body'):
        Item = ParsingerbotItem()
        Item['ling'] = str(response.url)
        ngaliase = re.findall("\w+.com", str(response.url))[0]      
        mmhtml = mbuh.xpath('//body').extract()
        cur.execute("select aliase, pattern, seq, opsi, replacer from tb_bersihin where aliase='"+ngaliase+"\' order by seq asc")
        for filde in cur.fetchall():
          faliase = filde[0]
          fpattern = filde[1]
          fseq = filde[2]
          fopsi = filde[3]
          freplacer = filde[4]
          print "faliase=%s,fpattern=%s,furutan=%d,fopsi=%s,freplacer=%s" % \
                    (faliase, fpattern, fseq, fopsi, freplacer )
          if ( freplacer  == "NO" ) : freplacer=""
          if ( fopsi == "NL" ) : fopsi="re.DOTALL"          
          k1 = re.sub(fpattern , freplacer, str(mmhtml), re.DOTALL)
          print k1
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you parsing HTML with regex - is there any particular reason why don't you use what Scrapy offers to parse HTML - XPath expressions and CSS selectors?

Comment: i'm new in scrapy and i think scrapy have limited parameters for parsing.. with regex, i can define the parameters wherever i want, not limited in html tags / dom parsing... but in pattern field above, i have some xpath expression too for simple parsing like finding the page title.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you're trying to match please. Scrapy is very good at matching.

Comment: @Steve indeed scrapy is very good and easy to use as matching, i'm using xpath to match the content title and date,working well... but the issues is in replace, not matching.. so i use regex stored in table

Comment: @Steve i have updated the question with an example.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i solved my own question, maybe i'm not good at describing my question above but all i want is make the result from first pattern to be the subject for the second pattern, and then continue to the next pattern from mysql table..

all i did was just changed

```
k1 = re.sub(fpattern , freplacer, str(mmhtml), re.DOTALL)
```

into

```
k1 = re.sub(fpattern , freplacer, k1)
```

and declare `k1 = str(mmhtml)` before loop `cur.fetchall()`

thank you

Answer (score 1):

@insecte, look at [this](https://github.com/scalingexcellence/scrapybook/blob/master/ch05/generic/generic/spiders/fromcsv.py) nice little spider. It reads [this](https://github.com/scalingexcellence/scrapybook/blob/master/ch05/generic/todo.csv) CSV file and does generic parsing from pages. Use this as a starting point and change the CSV file reading with the database reading. Highly likely you won't have 1000's of URLs so it's worth reading from the database only once and store the XPath expressions in memory. Does it help?

Comment: thank you for the response.. i'm trying to understand the code

Answer (score 0):

Your loop `for mbuh in response.xpath('//body')` only executes once as that xpath returns just one selector. Then you use `mmhtml = mbuh.xpath(etc)` which will always return the same data no matter what is in mbuh because the xpath starts with '//' which means 'search from the of the start of the page'. It will also extract the whole page as text.

I see why you are looping on cur.fetchall, but why are you looping on mbuh = response.xpath()? What did you expect that xpath to return?

Comment: i know the first loop only executes once, because i'm expecting only one result..  mmhtml is a subject (from `<body>` to `</body>` ) which i want to clean with the patterns that i put in the MySQL table